# Cloud Functions - update Firestore field set by const, not a static named field

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an online presence function that looks at realtime database to see if a unit has gone offline, and if so, updates a firestore field.

the realtime database goes like: "Client Name"/"Unit Number"

the firestore database goes like "Online Presence"/"Client Name"/"Unit Number"

The problem is that I can't seem to find out how to set the dynamically referenced "Unit Number" firestore field's value to "offline".  I can only set a static field like "Online" = "false"

Here is the Node.js function...

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database.ref('/{client}/{uid}').onUpdate(
async (change, context) => {

  const eventStatus = change.after.val();
  const client = context.params.client;
  const uid = context.params.uid;

     
  
  const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`Online Presence/${client}`);

  const statusSnapshot = await change.after.ref.once('value');
  const status = statusSnapshot.val();
  
  if (status === 'offline'){

   return userStatusFirestoreRef.set({
          uid: "false"
                }, {merge: true});

            }
});
```

the above will set a firestore field of 'Online Presence/"Client Name"/uid' = false.

instead, I'd like it to set a firestore field of 'Online Presence'/"Client Name"/"Unit Number"' = false.

the unit number is set as a const at the top, const uid = context.params.uid;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out that it was missing [] brackets.

by changing:

```
  return userStatusFirestoreRef.set({
      uid: "false"
            }, {merge: true});

        }
```

to:

```
  return userStatusFirestoreRef.set({
      [uid]: "false"
            }, {merge: true});

        }
```

now it properly writes the firestore field as the const that was declared at the top, instead of writing a literal string value field of 'uid'.